# On sequelize, "include" of "findOne" not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I made a simple test that is to search for an address (id = 4) and retrieve the user who is linked to that address.

Here are my Models:

*user.js*

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return sequelize.define('User', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
            allowNull: false,
            field: 'id',
            //primaryKey: true,
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            field: 'name',
        },
    }, {
        freezeTableName: true,
        tableName: 'user',
        createdAt: false,
        updatedAt: false,
        classMethods: {
            associate: function(models) {
                models.User.hasMany(models.UserAddress, { foreignKey: 'userId' });
            },
        },
    });
};
```

*user_address.js*

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return sequelize.define('UserAddress', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
            allowNull: false,
            field: 'id',
        },
        userId: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
            allowNull: false,
            field: 'user_id',
        },
        title: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: true,
            field: 'title',
        },
        address: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: true,
            field: 'address',
        },
    }, {
        freezeTableName: true,
        tableName: 'user_address',
        createdAt: false,
        updatedAt: false,
        classMethods: {
            associate: function(models) {
                models.UserAddress.hasOne(models.User, { foreignKey: 'id' });
            },
        },
    });
};
```

And here is my test file:

```
db.UserAddress.findOne({
    where: { id: 4 },
    include: [db.User],
}).then(function(address) {
    console.log('------------------------------ Address by "include"');
    console.log('Address title: '+address.title);
    console.log('User id: '+address.userId);
    if(address.User !== null) {
        console.log('User name: '+address.User.name);
    } else {
        console.log('User name: NO USER');
    }

    console.log('');
    address.getUser().then(function(user) {
        console.log('------------------------------ Address by "getUser"');
        console.log('Address title: '+address.title);
        console.log('User id: '+address.userId);
        if(user !== null) {
            console.log('User name: '+address.user.name);
        } else {
            console.log('User name: NO USER');
        }
        console.log('');
    });
});
```

I do a query with two tests:

- The first aims to recover the user directly via the variable "user", so thanks to "include" of the request.
- And the other also retrieve the user but this time via "getUser()".

Here is the result:

```
$ node test.js
Executing (default): SELECT `UserAddress`.`id`, `UserAddress`.`user_id` AS `userId`, `UserAddress`.`title`, `UserAddress`.`address`, `User`.`id` AS `User.id`, `User`.`name` AS `User.name` FROM `user_address` AS `UserAddress` LEFT OUTER JOIN `user` AS `User` ON `UserAddress`.`id` = `User`.`id` WHERE `UserAddress`.`id`=4;
------------------------------ Address by "include"
Address title: Test
User id: 3
User name: NO USER

Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `user` AS `User` WHERE (`User`.`id`=4);
------------------------------ Address by "getUser"
Address title: Test
User id: 3
User name: NO USER
```

One can observe that it is impossible to retrieve the result via "include" and "getUser()".
The error is visible in the log of SQL:

```
"include": LEFT OUTER JOIN `user` AS `User` ON `UserAddress`.`id` = `User`.`id`
and
"getUser()": SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `user` AS `User` WHERE (`User`.`id`=4);
```

While the correct answer should have been:

```
"include": LEFT OUTER JOIN `user` AS `User` ON `UserAddress`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`
and
"getUser()": SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `user` AS `User` WHERE (`User`.`id`=3);
```

So my question is, what is the configuration to put in my Model or my request for the result to be correct with "include" and "getUser()" ?

Thank you.

(Also posted on: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3182)

Comment: Something isn't quite right here: you show your SQL as having just `id`, but in user.js you have `userId`. Sequelize handles foreign keys strangely when they're not with default capitalization (camel case). What you could do is change the `foreignKey` field of the associations in both `user.js` and `user_address.js` until you get the proper query. That should only be a couple of tries. One way I've done it in the past was `models.User.hasMany(models.UserAddress, { foreignKey: 'user_id' });`
and `models.UserAddress.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'user_id' });`.

Comment: The solution was to give me on Github: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3182#issuecomment-75241849

Comment: Oh, well... at least I think I was right, apart from the capitalization of `user_id`. :) You could copy the solution here and mark the answer as accepted, so that others can see the solution as well.

Answer (score 3):

Answer from the [github page](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3182#issuecomment-75241849) - need to use `belongsTo` instead of `hasOne`.

user.js

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return sequelize.define('User', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
            allowNull: false,
            field: 'id',
            //primaryKey: true,
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            field: 'name',
        },
    }, {
        freezeTableName: true,
        tableName: 'user',
        createdAt: false,
        updatedAt: false,
        classMethods: {
            associate: function(models) {
                models.User.hasMany(models.UserAddress, { foreignKey: 'userId' });
            },
        },
    });
};
```

user_address.js

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return sequelize.define('UserAddress', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
            allowNull: false,
            field: 'id',
        },
        userId: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
            allowNull: false,
            field: 'user_id',
        },
        title: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: true,
            field: 'title',
        },
        address: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: true,
            field: 'address',
        },
    }, {
        freezeTableName: true,
        tableName: 'user_address',
        createdAt: false,
        updatedAt: false,
        classMethods: {
            associate: function(models) {
                models.UserAddress.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'userId' });
            },
        },
    });
};
```